terraform lambda resource policy issue
I am trying to add resource AWS IAM policy to the lambda function from Terraform and IAM policy does not have any condition but resource however Terraform is adding the same resource in condition.
  resource "aws_lambda_permission" "lambda_function" {
  statement_id = "AllowSecretsManagerInvoke"
  action = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.myfunction.function_name
  principal = "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn = aws_lambda_function.myfunction.arn
}

Ideally resource policy should be created as below
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "SecretsManagerInvoke",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:{region}:{account}:function:myfunction"
    }
  ]
}

But terraform is creating policy as below:
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowSecretsManagerInvoke",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:arn:aws:lambda:{region}:{account}:function:myfunction",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:lambda:arn:aws:lambda:{region}:{account}:function:myfunction"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}


Removing source_arn fixed the issue. The aws_lambda_permission resource in Terraform automatically adds a Condition when you specify the source_arn parameter.
 resource "aws_lambda_permission" "lambda_function" {
  statement_id = "AllowSecretsManagerInvoke"
  action = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.myfunction.function_name
  principal = "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"
}

